# HTTP POST code fails with Android 5.1

Tags: android, http, http-post, android-5.1.1-lollipop

following code worked fine until now (code snippets, not complete):

```
URL connectURL = new URL(remURL);    
c= (HttpURLConnection) connectURL.openConnection();
c.setDoOutput(true); // enable POST
c.setRequestMethod("POST");
c.addRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
c.addRequestProperty("Content-Length",""+post.length());
os = new DataOutputStream(c.getOutputStream());
os.write(post.getBytes());
os.flush();

rc = c.getResponseCode();
if (rc != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) 
{
   ...
   return null;
}

is=new BufferedInputStream(new DataInputStream(c.getInputStream()));
len= (int)c.getContentLength();

...

while ((bytesread != len) && (is.available()>0)) 
{
   actual = is.read(data, bytesread, len - bytesread);
   bytesread += actual;
}
```

Now when I try to run the same code on Android 5.1 I see following problems:

1. c.getContentLength() always returns a length of 0
2. when I ingore this content length size, and try to download the data, is.available() is always false

The POST-URL is OK and works, so the accessed server is available. When I try the same code with e.g. Android 4.2 everything works well.

So...any ideas what is different in 5.1?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe related to a change in default security policies? Might be worth investigating that.

Comment: `and try to download the data`. Do not use available. Your code cannot work. Just read lines from the input stream until the line is null. Google for convertinputstreamtostring.

Comment: @greenapps: the code definitely DID work until now...so is this a change in 5.1?

Comment: `Google for convertinputstreamtostring`